# Overloading "==" operator for numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading

I am defining a function in Python that needs to check

```
if a==b:
  do.stuff()
```

In principle, `a` and `b` could be numpy arrays or integers, and I would like my implementation to be robust against this. However, to check equality for a numpy array, one needs to append the boolean with all(), which will break the code when `a` and `b` are integers.

Is there a simple way to code the equality test so that it works regardless of whether `a` and `b` are integers or numpy arrays?

Comment: Have you tried using `type()`?

Comment: Sticking `all` on the comparison isn't even correct for arrays - you'll get a variety of false positives and exceptions when the arrays have mismatched shapes.

Comment: (Despite the exception message telling you to use `any` or `all`, using `any` or `all` is very rarely the right move when you get one of those exceptions. Usually the right move is something like `numpy.where` or `numpy.array_equal`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this that works for both arrays and integers(numbers):

```
if np.array_equal(a,b):
    do.stuff()
```

Comment: @mikefallopian glad it helped.

Comment: Mike, you might find it instructive to look at the code for `array_equal`.  It starts by turning the inputs into arrays.  That's a common step in `numpy` functions.